# How to display html and then Redirect to a download using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm completely new to Flask and web development so please ignore any lack of proper terminology that I'm probably using.

I'm trying to display a page that tells the user that their files are being packaged.  Once the packaging on the back end is done I'd like to redirect them back to the page they came from as well as send them a file to download.

I'm limited to using Flask and Python 2.7 for this task.

I've tried returning both the html and the `send_file(path_to_file)` function as a tuple, as well as trying to create a new thread for the `send_file()` function but neither worked.

I'm a at a loss as to what to try next.

Here is some code showing where I'm at right now:

```py
import backend
import threading
from flask import request, send_file

def get_package(post_data):
    file_path = backend.get_package(post_data)
    return send_file(file_path)

@app.route("/pkg_download", method=['POST'])
def pkg_download():
    post_data = dict(request.form.iterlists())
    result = threading.Thread(None, target=get_package, args=[post_data])
    result.start()

    html_dialog = "<p>Packaging Images</p>"
    return html_dialog
```

When I run the above I get this error:

`RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.`

instead of getting the html displayed and then the file downloading after the package is done zipping.

But again, I don't really know what I'm doing and this is probably the complete wrong way to approach this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to have the front end do the redirection so you just need to render the template and then the JavaScript can go to the download page

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do shouldn't be done in the API request to the server directly. Creating an archive may take some time and it's usually better to respond directly to the request you received and launch a background task to perform a longer operation.

Once the longer operation succeeds you can send a message to the client to tell him the archive is ready for him to download.

Implementation proposition:

- Your front-end send a request to your Flask server with the files the user want to compress
- You receive the files on Flask and save them somewhere
- From the same function, you launch a [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) task with information about the client who did the request and the paths of the files he uploaded
- You compress the files in the celery task, once succeeded you can send a notification to the user (To send the notification you could use a websocket that you send to the front-end)

This implementation would allow you to code the following logic and have this behavior in the front-end of your website:

- Create a websocket that is connected to your backend and that will allow you to communicate with the client
- The user selects the files he wants to compress
- You start to send them to your server (Flask API)
- You put a loading message saying his files are currently being uploaded
- When you receive the answer of the API request you could display a message indicating the success of the upload of files
- You put a message saying the compression of his files is currently being processed by your server
- When you front-end receive a websocket with the link of the archive you display it accordingly to the user

And voila you should be good to go.